# I want gradle to build only single class instead of the whole project

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio project I have a separate class where I experiment with java code. The class has method `public static void main(String[] args){}`

Right click on this class in project tree -> Run (Ctrl+Shift+F10)

And I noticed that gradle starts building the whole project. And it takes certain time but I want it to build and run only this one class. So it is as fast as possible.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try modifying your AndroidManifest file to run only the class you want as a main-launcher class:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme">

        <activity
            android:name=".RUN_YOUR_ACTIVITY"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes. I know. But it's building the whole project anyway.